# Changing data in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have data array

```
$data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

if i see on browser
I would like to change it so it's like this.

```
array(
 [0] => [1,2,3,4,5]
 [1] => [6,7,8,9,10]
)
```

I need help to change this.

Comment: Which pattern do you want to use?

Comment: `array_chunk()` maybe?

Comment: So, 5 in each? Or are there other specific conditions? Also, show us what you have tried.

Comment: simply array_chunk() if you need to break it after 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-chunk.php) to do this, here's a quick example.

```
<?php
$data = $data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$newData = array_chunk($array, 5));

print_r($newData);
```